# Rails/Ruby - Confused by this enum-related error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've created a concern that contains an enum listing possible gender values for use in forms and such:

genderable.rb

```
module Genderable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum gender: [:"Not Known", :"Male", :"Female", :"Not Applicable"]
  end

end
```

Here's where I include it in my model:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Genderable

  has_one :user_gender
  has_one :gender, :through => :user_gender

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_gender

end
```

Here's where I use it within my view:

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.select :gender, User.genders, :class => "form-control" %>
  <%= showErrorMessages("Gender", :gender) %>
</div>
```

Here's the markup that is generated for my view:

```
<select id="user_gender" name="user[gender]">
  <option value="0">Not Known</option>
  <option value="1">Male</option>
  <option value="2">Female</option>
  <option value="3">Not Applicable</option>
</select>
```

Here's the error message I get when attempting to submit the form relying upon all of the above:

[image: Here's the error message I get when attempting to submit the form relying upon all of the above:]

It seems that ActiveRecord dislikes the fact that the value for gender is a string and not an integer (I'm guessing!). Or maybe it dislikes that the value doesn't match one of the symbol values of the enum I created. I'm really not sure. Does anyone know what the problem is? Basically, I just want to update the user_genders table with the user's ID and the selected value.

Comment: Sorry, looked at your question a little more closely. You cannot do what you're doing. You cannot have an `enum :gender` and a `has_one :gender`. This obviously cannot work, how can Rails know whether you want the `enum` or the `has_one` when you do `record.gender`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the integer values to an `enum`. You need to assign the actual symbol.

For your view, you should use:

```
<%= f.select :gender, User.genders.keys, :class => "form-control" %>
```

In order to generate a select that looks like this:

```
<option value="Not Known">Not Known</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
<option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
```

Comment: I think the ERB select code in your response was lost.

Comment: Your example gives me option elements that look like this: <option value="0">0</option>

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `.keys`, not `.values`.

Comment: This gets me past the enum-related error, but now it looks like I'm attempting to send strings to the database, which isn't intended behavior. I'm receiving an error that reads: "can't write unknown attribute `gender'
".

Comment: Have you run your migrations? Perhaps there isn't a column in the users table yet.

Comment: I have. If I had to hazard a guess, there's probably an issue within the association among users, user_genders, and genders. I know that, in order to associate a user with a gender, I would need to update both user_id and gender_id within the user_genders table. I'm not sure how to do this, honestly. I could show you what I've tried in another question, if you're game.